# Conditional formating for spreadsheet with if, and, then

Tags: excel

So I have a chart I am trying to create conditional formatting for in excell. So I have a product order sheet and I have 2 different styles listed in column A, with multiple sizes listed in column B, and I want column C to enter the price based on the style they are ordering and the size they are ordering. How can I do that?
For example if column A is "male" and column B is "S" then column C would be $10 but if Column B is "L" then c would be $15, or if Column A was "woman" and Column B was "S" then C would be $5, etc. What I need is a formula that when I put the style in A and the size in B it will automatically enter the dollar amount for me in C. The price of the product depends on the style and the size.

[image: snip of the list]

Comment: i'm even ok with entering in multiple formulas, if I could get one that says if A1 is "male" and B1 is "L" then C1 is "20" if not nothing... and then I could just enter all the possible outcomes so it would do it. but the spread sheet is so large I don't want to keep looking up the scenarios and entering the amount if I can find a way for excel to do it for me. but I have been at this for days

Comment: Are you working in google sheets (as implied by your tagging) or in excel (as implied by your comment)? It might be useful to provide some sample data as well as any formulas you may have so far.

Comment: im working in Excel sorry it wasn't clear. I will create a example and hopefully it helps.

Comment: =IF(AND($E$3:$E$47="man",$F$3:$F$47="L"), "15.00", "") is the formula that I have in but nothing happens

Comment: You should be able to edit your original post. It would be better to put the information in there. I'd provide some sample data as well as expected outputs. Also, it's not entirely clear if you need help with a formula or if you need help with charting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to auto-populate column C based on the values in columns A and B, then the [sumifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function would be useful. You can create a master list of prices (if you don't have any already) such as

```
Col E   Col F  Col G
------- ------ ------
Style   Size   Price
male    S      10
male    M      15
male    L      20
female  S      12
female  M      17
female  L      22
```

Then you can take your orders list and apply the following function in cell C2.

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,E:E,A2,F:F,B2)
```

This will sum the values in column G provided that A2 matches in column E and B2 matches in column F. Here's the result.

```
Col A   Col B  Col C
------- ------ ------
Style   Size   Price
male    L      20
male    S      10
male    M      15
female  L      22
female  M      17
male    S      10
female  L      22
female  S      12
male    S      10
```

Comment: OMG thank you! I have been at this for days. I knew there HAD to be an easier way to do this. If the list was small it wouldn't be a big deal but some of these are several Excel pages long. Thank you again

Comment: Glad I could help. If your question is solved, it's good to mark the answer as accepted so others can focus on addressing unsolved questions. Also, you get 2 reputation points for accepting an answer which can help if you have questions later on.